# Common item selection - Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

OK, I know this should be easy but the solution is escaping me. I am doing some social network analysis in python and have a pandas Dataframe (connections) that contain data like this...

```
uid  |   name   |  fuID  |  friendName   | 
1    |  Bob     |   f1   |   Jimmy       |
1    |  Bob     |   f2   |   Frank       |
1    |  Bob     |   f3   |   Sal         |
2    |  Mark    |   f4   |   Leon        |
2    |  Mark    |   f1   |   Jimmy       |
2    |  Mark    |   f5   |   Artie       |
3    |  Steve   |   f1   |   Jimmy       |
3    |  Steve   |   f5   |   Artie       |
3    |  Steve   |   f6   |   Samuel      |
```

The goal is to find all the shared friends, in other words I would like to be able to find all of the friendName/fuIDs that have more than one connection and what those connections are. For example, Jimmy is connected to Bob, Mark and Steve.

I can create a groupby easily enough ... connections.groupby("uid") and assumed there was a way to then compare against the groups to find the in common items, but I've hit a wall. I started building a complex for loop to iterate through the groups and just stopped, knowing that there must be a simple way to do this that I'm just missing.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You may be better off using networkx to find cliques rather than pandas

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I've played with this some now and that certainly helps on the visualization front. It hadn't dawned on me to use networkx for the exploratory piece of the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you were nearly there --

```
fdfg = connections.groupby('friendName')
for k, v in fdfg:
    if len(v) > 1:
        print k
        print v.name
```

> ```
> Artie
> 5     Mark
> 7    Steve
> Name: name, dtype: object
> Jimmy
> 0      Bob
> 4     Mark
> 6    Steve
> Name: name, dtype: object
> ```

There probably is an even more succinct way to do it.

Comment: ahhh.... see, I was grouping on the main individuals (hubs) not the secondary people (spokes) and was therefore missing the simple solution to be able to isolate the repetitive values.

Much appreciated cphlewis